# Понятное понимание принципов работы PoW и PoS

Tags: blockchain

Почему на PoS не нужны большие вычислительные мощности, ведь там тоже есть математика и расчеты? Насколько я понял тему, это выглядит следующим образом, но если я не прав поправьте меня. В этом и есть основной вопрос.

В случае с proof of work вознаграждение за создание нового блока забирает тот, кто первый решил сложную математическую задачу, которая ни как не относится к самим транзакциям. То есть, сложность задачи предназначена для отсеивания маленьких майнеров(с маленькими вычислительными мощностями), а не для математических вычислений транзакций и проверки их. Математическая задача является пропуском в "кабинет бухгалтера", который записывает транзакции в "учетную книгу"(блок) и именно по этому PoW считается не эффективным, так как в гонке за награду вычислительные мощности участников стали расти в геометрической прогрессии, а нужны они только для выбора майнера. По просту говоря, записать новый блог может любой и для этого хватит и калькулятора, но сеть доверяет только тому у кого вычислительные мощности больше, так устроен механизм работы PoW.

В случае с PoS этим доверием наделяется тот, у кого денег больше в кармане. Если ты богатый, значит мы тебе верим. Тут количество богатства определяет процент от общего количество записываемых блоков. Владеешь 70% токенов проекта, будешь записывать 70% блоков. Вычислительные мощности для решения задачи по записи блока и его проверки нужны не большие, как в первом, так и во втором случае. И если я все правильно понял, у меня вопрос: Какие вычислительные мощности нужны для записи самого блока, а не для прелюдий по допуску? И из чего состоит эта задача(проверить транзакции, вычесть или прибавить из баланса, выполнить функцию и пр.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. PoW основан на концепции определения случайного участника, который будет формировать блок и, следовательно, получит вознаграждение за него. Для этого участники решают сложную вычислительную задачу не имеющую аналитического решения - только перебор. Естественно, что каждый из участников хочет иметь максимальную  вероятность получения вознаграждения за формирование блока, из-за чего они и наращивают свои вычислительные мощности.
2. PoS основан на несколько иной концепции - маловероятно, что владелец значительной суммы нативных токенов (stake) будет стремится к дискредитации сети , так как это неизбежно приведет к потере средств, вложенных им в эти нативные токены. Соответственно, вероятность формирования блока (и получения вознаграждения) некоторым образом определяется соотношением долей владения участников (при этом список причастных к майнингу может быть ограничен некой минимально долей). Для обеспечения вероятностного разброса здесь тоже может быть использована сложная вычислительная задача, но ее влияние сказывается только для при сравнимых долях владения участников. Например, за счет обратной зависимости числа нулей в "счастливом хэше" от доли владения.
3. Насколько я знаю на текущий момент сходимость PoS теоритически не доказана, в отличии от PoW.