# Перевести время UTC на часовой пояс Екатеринбурга

Tags: python, pandas

Помогите перевести UTC время, во время Екатеринбурга. Вот функция получения данных, которая выводит время в UTC.

```
def getminutedata(symbol, interval, lookback):
     frame = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol, interval, lookback + 'min ago UTC'))
     frame = frame.iloc[:,:6]
     frame.columns = ['Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
     frame = frame.set_index('Time')
     frame.index = pd.to_datetime(frame.index, unit='ms')
     frame = frame.astype(float)
     return frame
```

Как мне изменить время на Екатеринбург. Помогите, кто шарит. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, почему вы регулярно размещаете тут вопросы, но затем обычно  их не принимаете и не комментируете (даже простым "спасибо"), включая и случаи развернутых ответов?

Comment: Добрый день. На самом деле отвечаю и комментирую. Последний вопрос только пропустил, но сейчас добавлю все.

Comment: Спасибо, что отреагировали. Советаю так и в дальнейшем действовать. А на момент, когда я посмотрел, у вас было пропущено 5 из 7 данных ответов. Обратите внимание, что сейчас пропущен: <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430183/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-pow-%d0%b8-pos>

Comment: Рекомендую в вопросе указать формат, в котором выводятся данные и пример вывода, если хочется ответ и от тех, кто с Pandas не знаком. Все, что потом надо сделать - прибавить к нему разницу в пять часов, если не хочется возиться с параметром utc в pd.to_datetime.

Comment: Все поправил. Формат вывода времени - 2022-07-27 05:23:00. Нагуглил, что можно прибавлять часы просто вот таким образом - offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=3) tz = datetime.timezone(offset, name='МСК'), но как это адаптировать в коде не понимаю пока.

Comment: формат - строковый? Что выдает `type(frame.index)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо строчку

```
frame.index = pd.to_datetime(frame.index, unit='ms')
```

Заменить на

```
frame.Time = pd.to_datetime(frame.Time, unit='ms').apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Asia/Yekaterinburg')).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```